# Scala/Intellij: block after false if statement is entered

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

It is the weirdest thing that I have seen with my IntelliJ when working on a sbt project - I can share more details about the use case if necessary.

I have an if statement and in debug I observe that the block following it is entered when that statement is evaluated to false.

I tried running `sbt compile`, `sbt reload`. I've also invalidated caches and restarted IntelliJ.

This is the code:

```
class MedianOf3Partitioning[T: ClassTag : Ordering] extends QuickSort[T] with MedianOfPartitioning[T] {

  protected val MEDIAN_OF = 3

  override protected def sort(a: Array[T], lo: Int, hi: Int): Array[T] = {
    if (hi > lo || (hi - lo) > MEDIAN_OF) {
      val sampleArray = getSample(a.slice(lo, hi), MEDIAN_OF)
      patchArray(a, lo, hi, sampleArray)
      val j = partition(a, lo, hi)
      sort(a, lo, j - 1)
      sort(a, j + 1, hi)
    } else return super.sort(a, lo, hi)

  }
}
```

And here's a screenshot from a debug session that demonstrates what is going on:

[image: How is this even possible?]

So both of the conditions are false, but the code in braces following the statement is entered.

My IntelliJ version is 2018.3

**Update**

I have been executing the code by running this test class:

```
class MedianOf3PartitioningSpec extends BaseSpec {

  private val testCase: Array[Char] = "EASYQUICKSORTQUESTION" toCharArray

  behavior of "MedianOf3PartitioningSpec"

  it should "sort" in {
    val medianOf3Partitioning = new MedianOf3Partitioning[Char]
    val maybeSortedArray = medianOf3Partitioning sort(testCase)
    maybeSortedArray shouldBe sorted
  }

}
```

I was running it using IntelliJ (as I normally do). I just tried plain command line `testOnly *MedianOf3PartitioningSpec` but it fails for the same reason.

If I let the code run (ignoring this weird observation that I shared above) then the test fails with this:

```
[info] - should sort *** FAILED ***
[info]   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
[info]   at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:388)
[info]   at scala.util.Random.nextInt(Random.scala:66)
[info]   at ca.vgorcinschi.algorithms2_3.MedianOfPartitioning.getSample(MedianOfPartitioning.scala:14)
[info]   at ca.vgorcinschi.algorithms2_3.MedianOfPartitioning.getSample$(MedianOfPartitioning.scala:13)
[info]   at ca.vgorcinschi.algorithms2_3.MedianOf3Partitioning.getSample(MedianOf3Partitioning.scala:16)
[info]   at ca.vgorcinschi.algorithms2_3.MedianOf3Partitioning.sort(MedianOf3Partitioning.scala:22)
[info]   at ca.vgorcinschi.algorithms2_3.MedianOf3Partitioning.sort(MedianOf3Partitioning.scala:25)
[info]   at ca.vgorcinschi.algorithms2_3.MedianOf3Partitioning.sort(MedianOf3Partitioning.scala:26)
[info]   at ca.vgorcinschi.algorithms2_3.QuickSort.sort(QuickSort.scala:13)
[info]   at ca.vgorcinschi.algorithms2_3.MedianOf3PartitioningSpec.$anonfun$new$1(MedianOf3PartitioningSpec.scala:13)
```

...where `getSample` is doing this:

```
trait MedianOfPartitioning [T] {

  this: BaseSort[T] =>

  protected val MEDIAN_OF: Int

  protected def getSample(a: Array[T], medianOf: Int): Array[T] = {
    val sampleArrayOffset = Random.nextInt(a.length - medianOf)
    a.slice(sampleArrayOffset, sampleArrayOffset + medianOf)
  }

  /**
    * Mutate the main array to have at its head the smallest value from sample
    * array and at its last index the biggest value from sample array
    * @param a - target array
    * @param sampleArray - size should be equal to {@link MEDIAN_OF}
    */
  def patchArray(a: Array[T], lo: Int, hi: Int, sampleArray: Array[T]): Unit = {
    val (minVal, maxVal) = ((sampleArray.head, sampleArray.head) /: sampleArray) { case ((tempMin, tempMax), current) =>
      (min(tempMin, current), max(tempMax, current))
    }
    exch(a, a.indexOf(minVal), lo)
    exch(a, a.indexOf(maxVal), hi)
  }
}
```

But should that if statement evaluated correctly the `getSample` shouldn't be entered in the first place (that is the intention). Probably there's an elephant in the room that I'm not seeing, but I'd be grateful if someone could point it to me :-)

Comment: You need to click on that light bulb next to the `return` expression :)

Comment: Have you tried to delete the `return` statement? as Tim says. It should not be used in Scala, and maybe that is causing the problem.

Comment: Alas, it is not the `return` keyword. `return` is a late addition to the code in a desperate attempt to make it work (after it was already failing for the same reason).

Comment: Could you also show your `patchArray` implementation? Or ideally create a full [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The test `(hi - lo) > MEDIAN_OF` can only be true if `hi > lo` (or `MEDIAN_OF` is negative) so this test seems unnecessary. Perhaps you are assuming that `hi` is at least 4 greater than `lo`?

Comment: @SergGr, I've added the method.

Comment: @Tim, you can add your suggestion as the right answer. Removing the first condition inside if made it work. The only thing that I modified in addition after was change the assert statement to `maybeSortedArray shouldEqual testCase.sorted`, so now the test succeeds too. 

What I still don't understand is that on the screenshot the first condition is still false, so it shouldn't enter the block...